# How to prove that every regular ordinal is a cardinal?

Tags: set-theory

I know that an ordinal is regular if its equal to is cofinality, but how is that related to cardinal?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What is your definition of cofinality? According to one common definition, "cofinality" is the smallest _cardinality_ of a cofinal subset, so saying that $\alpha$ equals its cofinality means that $\alpha$ equals some cardinal number, so it must _be_ that cardinal number.

Comment: You need a bit more work if the cofinality is the smallest _order type_ of a cofinal subset, though.